# Mysql Undocumented Default Setting for sort_buffer_size in Options File

Tags: mysql

From a recent install of MySQL Workbench V. 6.2 (MySQL 5.6), while inspecting the options file (Edit > Preferences > General) I see that sort_buffer_size is set to `256k\n256k`.

What does the `\n256k` part of this setting mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` normally means newline, so what that text means is

```
256k
256k
```

The documentation for [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) suggests it is only expecting a single value. My guess is that it is either an incorrect value in my.ini, parsing the my.ini incorrectly of there is a bug in the way workbench is displaying the value.